# Finding subgraphs homeomorphic to k5 or k3,3

Tags: optimization, graph-theory, clique, planar-graph, clique-problem

Given a simple graph, problem is to check if there is a subgraph homeomorphic to k5 or k3,3, and if there is, output which one is present(k5 or k3,3 or both). I need a reasonably fast algorithm that would work on graphs with 15 vertices in under few minutes. I know that I could check if one of those 2 graphs is contained with Tarjan's algorithm for graph planarity, but I also want to know which one it is.

I am coding in c++ and best solution I have is to take all subsets of edges, but that's very expensive. On the other hand, in my first try I fixed vertices, but than I couldn't handle checking if the subgraph is homeomorphic to k5 ot k3,3. I tried removing 2-degree vertices and connecting the neighbours, but there are still edges that should be ignored and I don't see a way to efficiently remove them.

Comment: Hello. This is a problem that has been studied a lot but is quite hard, and there are several C++ libraries that provide a function just for this. I doubt you can do better by coding your own function.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Stef Hmm, I tried to find it, but didn't succeed. Most things just check if a graph is planar, which isn't sufficient for my needs. If you know exact resource where I can find it, it would be very useful.

Comment: @ReljaŠegvić Have you tried searching with keywords "subgraph isomorphism c++"?

Comment: My first thought was that determining whether a graph H is homeomorphic to a subgraph of graph G, is NP-complete, (you could take H as a Hamiltonian cycle e.g. for a proof), but if you fix H to be K3,3 or K5 this is not the case, as "their size is fixed". You could just "brute force it" (big degree polynomial time though). On the other hand, you said what you need is to (just) find which ones are present. I'd check out other planarity testing algorithms and see if any can tell. The paper describing the edge addition algorithm at first glance seems to have potential (nonplanarity minors part?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient solution is not to look directly for K<sub>5</sub> or K<sub>3,3</sub> sub-graphs but to try to build a planar embedding of the graph and when it fails then extract the failing sub-graph based upon the part of the embedding that failed.

- Hopcroft and Tarjan published the first [linear-time planarity testing algorithm in 1974](https://doi.org/10.1145%2F321850.321852) and the methodology is commonly known "path-addition".

  It works by:

  - Using a DFS to separate the graph into bi-connected components.
  - Then for each bi-connected component, ordering the edges into a hierarchy of paths such that the first path of the bi-connected component is a cycle (creating two faces inside and outside the cycle) and then each successive path connects to its parent path and to an ancestor path within the hierarchy;
  - The cycle, trivially, creates two faces within the embedding (inside and outside the cycle) and then each successive path bisects one of the previous faces separating it into two sub-faces.
  - Through maintaining a pair of linked-lists representing left-right (or inside-outside), the algorithm tries to embed each successive path onto the inside face and will check whether this conflicts with the currently embedded paths and either swap the current path or a block of previously embedded paths from the inside to the outside (they never get swapped back from outside to inside).
  - When a path cannot be embedded into either the inside or an outside face then the graph is non-planar.
- In 1976, [Evan and Tarjan](https://doi.org/10.1016%2F0304-3975%2876%2990086-4) published a linear-time algorithm using a "vertex-addition" methodology based on a PQ-tree data structure.
- In 1984, [Williamson](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1634.322451) extended H&T's algorithm to extract the Kuratowski sub-graphs.
- In 2004, [Boyer and Myrvold](https://doi.org/10.7155%2Fjgaa.00091) published a linear-time algorithm using an "edge-addition" methodology based on a PC-tree data structure and, in 2007, it was [extended to extract a Kuratowski sub-graph](https://doi.org/10.1007%2F978-3-540-77537-9_17).

There are plenty more papers that could be referenced including: [Ulric - The left-right planarity test (PDF)](http://www.uni-konstanz.de/algo/publications/b-lrpt-sub.pdf) and [Taylor - Planarity Testing by Path Addition](https://archive.org/details/PlanarityTestingByPathAddition/page/n43/mode/2up) (which both explain more of the mathematics behind H&Ts algorithm and the latter includes source code to generates all possible combinations of planar embeddings).

There are existing C/C++ libraries that implement some these algorithms including:

- [LEDA](https://www.algorithmic-solutions.info/leda_guide/graph_algorithms/planar_algorithms.html)
- [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/graph/doc/boyer_myrvold.html) - with an [example page for extracting Kuratowski sub-graphs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/graph/example/kuratowski_subgraph.cpp)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe SageMath can do something. It has a wrapper for Boyer’s (C) planarity algorithm. The following is a 27-vertex graph for example. It just takes 296 µs in my computer.

```
sage: G = graphs.SchlaefliGraph()
sage: G.is_planar()
sage: %time s=G.is_planar(kuratowski=True)
sage: s[1]
```

[image]

[image]